# Graph: Does simple path mean no repeated vertices or edges?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, definition, proof-explanation

I'm reading *Discrete Mathematics and It's application, Rosen, 7-th ed.*. By the definition, a simple path of undirected graph contains *no repeated edges*

[image]

But in the proof of following theorem it seems like the definition becomes *no repeated vertices*

[image]

And in the remark following the definition it says: *When this terminology is used, the terminology **path** is often used for a trail with no repeated vertices, $\color{red}{\textrm{conflicting}}$ with the terminology in Definition 1*.

[image]

But my understanding is

$$\textrm{repeated edges} \implies \textrm{repeated vertices}$$

[image]

-

There are two possible cases with definition 1, and the subscripts of the resulting path of both are the same as the one in the book, but in one case the path will be cut into two with the statement *[...] by deleting the edges correspoding to the vertex sequence $x_i,\dots, x_{j-1}$.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like your last observation is being used implicitly in the proof.  Namely, we suppose the shortest path isn't simple; that is, it has a repeated edge.  This implies that it has a repeated vertex, which can then be used to shorten the path and get a contradiction.

Comment: @RaviFernando: You're right the subscripts are correct but check my update.

Comment: I appreciate this book but it seems like the proof and the definition are not sync-updated. I guess it use the definition as in the remark and update the definition with the edge one later.

Comment: I recognize that graph theory terminology is notoriously non-standard, but I will just add that I’ve always thought “walk” is most general, “trail” is no repeated edges, and “path” is no repeated vertices. I think that’s from West.